# Laravel Sail Up never finishes building during GPG command

Tags: laravel, docker, wsl-2, laravel-sail

I'm trying to setup the dev environment for an existing project on another computer under WSL2 and Windows 10. Having installed the project from its own repo with `composer install` and making sure a basic .env file is in place, I ran `/vendor/bin/sail up` to do the initial build.

Docker starts normally, but then during stage 4 of 11 `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install....`, it just halts when it gets to the line `gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created` the build halts, the clock is still ticking but the operation never finishes.

I'm able to hit Ctrl + C and it Cancels cleanly.

Editing Laravel's dockerfile, I added a -v to the `gpg --recv-key ...` line in the script and got additional output with the operation halting after `gpg: connection to dirmngr established` instead.

I'm running Ubuntu under WSL2, fully updated, docker freshly installed and configured to talk to it as on my other machine where I'm not having any issues.

Comment: There's a PR that has been accepted that fixes this issue, so this shouldn't be an issue for long. https://github.com/laravel/sail/pull/508

Answer (score 14):

Removing the portnumber (`:80`) for the keyserver from the PHP 8.x docker file seems to be a workaround for this problem.

```
 echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
```

Tested with PHP 8.1.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/503#issuecomment-1336273951

Comment: Worked also for me, thanks

Comment: Also worked for me on PHP 8.0 Sail Docker File! Gracias