# Laravel on WSL not building

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I'm trying to build a project on a Linux Ubuntu 22.04, under Windows 11 22H2 Wsl2.
But when i run `./vendor/bin/sail up` or `./vendor/bin/sail up -d` I'm blocked by a infinity step:

```bash
[+] Building 663.1s (7/15)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04                                    0.8s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:4b1d0c4a2d2aaf63b37111f34eb9fa89fa1bf53dd6  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 99B                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                           0.0s-
 => CACHED [ 3/11] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezone  0.0si
 => [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip un  662.2s
 => => # Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20211016) ...
 => => # Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
 => => # 0 added, 0 removed; done.
 => => # Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
 => => # done.
 => => # gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
```

[image: infinity step]

Last night I let the build running on this step all night long.

I tried to re-install the packages (php, wsl, ubuntu 22.04 distro, composer and node and npm under nvm), and re-clone the project, but nothing happen.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try running it with flags `--progress=plain --verbose` in case there's more indication as to where it is stuck

Comment: return `unknown flag: --progress` :(

Comment: Try that with `sail build` instead of `up`

Comment: same error: #8 96.30 0 added, 0 removed; done.
#8 96.30 Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
#8 96.30 done.
#8 96.33 gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created

Comment: This solution works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74675546/6853003 Thank You all.