# Laravel install via Docker on WSL2 never stops building

Tags: laravel, docker, wsl-2

I'm trying to install a fresh Laravel 9 on Windows 10/WSL 2 with Docker. I followed the documentation and once I run the first command it gets stuck during building when it gets to the 4/11 stage, running endlessly until I have to cancel.

Here is what it looks like in the Terminal:

```
 => [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervis  167.8s
 => => # Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20211016ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
 => => # Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
 => => # 0 added, 0 removed; done.
 => => # Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
 => => # done.
 => => # gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
```

I used Unbuntu and Docker is fresh install. I don't understand what seems to be the problem here.

Honestly I didn't try much, I have no idea what the issue is...

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74650090/laravel-sail-up-never-finishes-building-during-gpg-command though that is about sail specifically

Comment: @apokryfos It does seem related, but I didn't get to even go through the first step. And I have no idea how to "remove the portnumber (:80) for the keyserver from the PHP 8.x docker file".

Comment: depending on the build i have to wait around a hour for some builds... thats just a docker downside i dont know why it takes forever in some builds. Have you tried to let it run for an hour before? from what i can see this step is only 167s so far. Even my React scripts install (for example not related) takes 90-120s and thats a relative small download

Comment: @Daniel Well I tried several times and I think I went somewhere around 350-400s. I can try to let it run for an hour but I sincerely doubt this will work.

Comment: @Exoseed to "debug" it you can also exclude services and see which of those takes so long. or if it would continue.

Comment: That refers to [this line](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile#L21) of the sail Dockerfile.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry if this is a stupid question but how do I change this line exactly?

Comment: If you are using sail this file is under vendon/laravel/sail/runtimes/x.y (x.y depends on what version of PHP you are using).